# Find second smallest within 3 numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, math

I have received an assignment on below problem:

The question requires me to find the second smallest of three numbers without any use of followings:

```
if-else statements, ternary operators or loops
```

and with the help of `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`.

Also, I can't import anything other than the `Scanner` class.

This is what I've done till now:

```
Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in);
int a, b, c, sec;
System.out.print("Enter three numbers.\n>  ");
a = N.nextInt();
b = N.nextInt();
c = N.nextInt();
sec=(a>b)? (b>c)? b : c : (a>c)? a : c;
System.out.print(sec);
```

Comment: We' re not here to do your homework for you. Please post what you have tried till now

Comment: Well, I have done the program with if-else statements, but question forbids me from doing that

Comment: @weakit Show it to us then.

Comment: You can do a lot with just `max()` and `min()`, especially if you only have 3 numbers to worry about. Have you tried combining them in any way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty goofy

Comment: tip: min = smallest, max = biggest. What remains?

Comment: Write down 3 numbers as well as their min and max on a piece of paper, then try adding/subtracting/multiplying/dividing them until you figure out how to get to the second smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given three numbers `a`, `b` and `c`, you can get the "*second smallest*" in a single line of code:

```
int second = Math.max(Math.min(a,b), Math.min(Math.max(a,b),c));
```

Please note it only uses `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to achieve the task.
It doesn't even use addition or subtraction!

**Here is a test case:**

```
a = 7, b = 2, c = 8.
second = max(min(7,2), min(max(7,2),8)) = max(2, min(7,8)) = max(2, 7) = 7
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the second smallest number by subtract min and max from the sum of three numbers. Assume three numbers are `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
int res = a + b + c - min - max;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add the numbers to an array and sort it. The number at index `1` is the second smallest.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[3];
    System.out.print("Enter three numbers.\n>  ");
    numbers[0] = N.nextInt();
    numbers[1] = N.nextInt();
    numbers[2] = N.nextInt();
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.print(numbers[1]);
  }
```